# How to insert html tags to a node content?

Tags: theming

I am wondering is it possible to insert a plain full html tags to a node content? Currently I have a node content type having a list of fields, but if I add some html tags in tpl.php file for that node, the html tags are actually outside the main content of the node field (but I want to put new-added html tags inside that.)

Can anyone brief me what is the best way of doing that?

Regards!

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're trying to implement. There are a multitude of ways to inject and override markup into the DOM. My guess is you're trying to use a textarea field which is having tags stripped by default input filters. Setting up wysiwyg editing and input filters is a subject too broad for a single question here.

Comment: Have you tried just entering HTML into the node body field?

Comment: Thanks dude and sorry for my unclear description. So is there any way that I can create a field which allows users manually input html format text? I have tried this several ways including textarea field, but nothing works for me. If you know the solution, would you mind copy some sample codes for me? Hope that is clear and thanks for your time.

Comment: @murraybiscuit, you are right, I actually want to use textarea field, however I am still novice in drupal, so would you mind to provide any sample codes and screenshots? Thanks again!

Comment: By design, Drupal comes with _very_ limited content editing features enabled. This is to keep the footprint small and for security reasons. This was a very frustrating omission for me as a new  user, but the reasons became evident later on. Everybody has their own approach to this problem, but it's a topic too broad for a Q&A format like this. My recommendation would be to install the ckeditor and elfinder modules with respective libraries, and then follow @argiepiano's advice in the answer section. Along the way, you may want to add other filter modules, the token module etc.

Comment: cool! Thanks for providing such good modules which are quite new to me, I think that is enough for solving my problem and I am going to give it go!

Answer (score 4):

To use html tags in the Body field of a Basic page content type (for example) you need to select "Full HTML" or "Filtered HTML" in the "Text format" dropdown menu below the input text box (see image). As far as I know, only fields of type "Long text and summary" and "Long text" allow you to select Full or Filtered HTML.

To configure text formats and permissions go to Configuration -> Content authoring -> Text formats (www.example.com/admin/config/content/formats).

[image]

For more information see [Text filters and Input Formats](https://www.drupal.org/node/213156).

Comment: Thanks for posting! I think I will give it go combining with yours and @murraybiscuit's together.